# Including js file in html properly with functions

Tags: javascript, html

i have 2 files....one html and one js....

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>

    <title> Sign In And Registration Page </title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="headerTag">
    </div>

    ///codes here....

</body>
</html>
```

js code:
some functions here performed on click operation.....

```
 function onClickOperation ()
    {
        ///here codes..
    }
```

problem is that the functions are not being called...when i put the same js code in the html file directly, it works....what do i have to do to load those functions from separate js file?

Comment: Please add html tag where you are calling the function, and where do you have the two file, in the same dir o not ?

Answer (score 1):

external.js should have the code called after DOM has finished loading like so

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
// code here
});
```

or it should be included inside the `body` tag below the DOM elements it should interact with

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the script in the body and just before the `</body>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Sign In And Registration Page </title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="headerTag">
    </div>

    ///codes here....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```